# Backbone getter returning nothing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backbone.js

Struggling with Backbone..

I am amending an opensource project and have the following code

```
    var tt = new Request();
    tt.set("url", base);  
    tt.set("method","OPTIONS");  
    tt.send("text","display");

    var resp = tt.get("response");
    var text = resp.get("text");

    console.log(resp);
    console.log("text",text.length);
```

Use the chrome developer tools I can see "resp" model in detail so that looks good.

[image]

If I try and get the value of the "text" item from the model it returns an empty string, yet in the console it clearly has some text in it.

What am I doing wrong?﻿

Comment: Asyncroniously request )) Add success callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you try to console.log "text" in the success callback of the request. I am assuming that the request class would make an async call to some service and provide a way for you to hook into the success or error cases.
HTH!